# Centrifugal pump head-flow prediction with CFD

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, cfd, turbomachinery

Given a volute pump casing, the impeller, and RPM how would one obtain a simulated head-flow graph? As for what I have seen in research papers most methods already assume input flowrate / pressure and even output head. However, in my case I do not know the inlet flowrate. It is determined by the impeller itself, right?

What I'm asking for is a globally outlined procedure of how such a problem could be solved. Mainly, what should be assumed and what will be simulated.

The pump has an inlet hose into a water reservoir (say h meters below inlet) and is fully primed/submerged in water. RPM is known as well as are the CAD models of pump and impeller.

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use CFD simulation of a given pump geometry to predict a performance curve for the pumps volumetric flow rate vs. a range of pressure difference (head) that the pump is seeing.  Advanced tools can even take into account the onset of cavitation, which will limit the operating range of the pump.  [Here is a good summary](https://www.simscale.com/blog/analysis-of-cavitation-effects-pumps/) of how this analysis is routinely done in the cloud-based CFD platform SimScale.